# Scene lightning is wrong when scene is loaded from a different scene

Tags: unity, lighting

I have a problem with the light in my scene. If I start the scene directly, it looks like I want it to be. If I load the scene from another, the light is too dim. Lighting is still applied, but everything is darker than it is supposed to be.

Used version is 2021.1.15f1, there is no lighting selected under Rendering/ Lighting/ Scene.

There is no code that is manipulating the lighting, a single directional light is used. If I deactivate the spot light, it gets even darker.

Loading the scene directly:
[image]

Loading the scene from a different scene:
[image]

Directional light settings:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that my Lighting Settings went corrupt and Unity went back on default settings, similar to when none are added. Unlike when they are missing fully, the error did not throw the usual "Lighting has been disabled" or similar errors. Deleting them from Lighting Settings in all scenes, generating new settings and assigning them again fixed the problem.

If someone else is stumbling to something similar, it can be found under Window/ Rendering/ Lighting.

Comment: Just dropped in to say I had the same problem and the solution you posted worked for me as well! Big thanks for following up on the original question