# The lighting result is wrong when switching scene in Unity

Tags: unity, camera, lighting

When I use `SceneManager.LoadScene()` to switch between scenes the result of lighting in loaded scene is wrong.  However if I open the scene solely the lighting become normal.  I'm pretty sure that I am not touching any code that might influence the light or camera setting while switching scene.

Here's the [demo of this problem](https://youtu.be/qKgQyviidIU) and fraction of the code (when choosing the first option it will switch to `DefaultScene` which I open it solely later).

```
public void SwitchToDefault()
{
   //Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
   SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
}
```

Comment: [Does this prior Q&A about similar symptoms solve your problem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198695/39518)? Also, note that code should be shared as text, never as an image.

Comment: Most tutorial never touch that and for a single scene it works out of the box. Check the linked question and most likely you never generated a lightning setting

Comment: The solution given by the link do solve the problem.Thanks to you all for giving me advice.